# Rails number_to_percentage and sub weird behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to replace big % numbers to shorters versions (10000% -> 10k%). Generally code works, but if `number_to_percentage` used it stop working (with *TOTALY SAME* string).

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.2)
2.3.1 :001 > "10000.000%".bytes
=> [49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 37]    
2.3.1 :002 > helper.number_to_percentage(10000).bytes
=> [49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 37] # totally same
2.3.1 :003 > helper.number_to_percentage(10000).sub(/(\d\d)\d\d\d(?:[.,]\d+)?\%$/){ "#{$1}k%" }
=> "k%"  # doesn't work
2.3.1 :004 > "10000.000%".sub(/(\d\d)\d\d\d(?:[.,]\d+)?\%$/){ "#{$1}k%" }
=> "10k%" # works
```

What can cause this? Any ideas?

Comment: What's your Ruby and Rails version? It works in Ruby 2.4.1p111 and Rails 5.1.3.

Comment: @GregNavis Are you sure?? One thing I found is that if you run `"10000.000%".sub(...)` **first**, then `$1` gets set. So, `number_to_percentage(10000).sub(...)` works *if* you run that first method **first**!

Comment: ruby 2.3.1 and rails  5.1.2

Comment: Good point, @TomLord. This is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference is:

```
"10000.000%".class #=> String
number_to_percentage(10000).class # => ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer
```

`ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer` is a subclass of `String`, and contains the concept of `UNSAFE_STRING_METHODS` (including `sub` and `gsub`). This concept is useful for rails views (which is where `number_to_percentage` is normally used!), in relation to security; preventing XSS vulnerabilities.

A workaround would be to explicitly convert the variable to a `String`:

```
number_to_percentage(10000).to_str.sub(/(\d\d)\d\d\d(?:[.,]\d+)?\%$/){ "#{$1}k%" }
=> "10k%"
```

(Note that it's **`to_str`**, not `to_s`! `to_s` just returns `self`, i.e. an instance of `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`; whereas `to_str` returns a regular `String`.)

[`This article`](https://makandracards.com/makandra/11171-how-to-fix-gsub-on-safebuffer-objects), and [`this rails issue`](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1555) go into more detail on the issue.

Alternatively, you could write your code like this, and it works as expected:

```
number_to_percentage(10000).sub(/(\d\d)\d\d\d(?:[.,]\d+)?%$/, '\1k%')
#=> "10k%"
```

I would actually prefer this approach, since you are no longer relying on modification to the (non-threadsafe) global variable.

Comment: Thank , i also found way with \1 but still very curious why original codes isn't working (but working with literal!)

Comment: @valodzka Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Because number_to_percentage returns an ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer and not a String.

```
helper.number_to_percentage(10000).class # => ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer
```

ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer (which is a subclass of String) does some magic around unsafe methods like sub. That's why you can have some surprises.